# Is there a way to re-use thread workers in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm writing some open cv code that could be easily parallelized. But I'm running into an issue. Examples of python multi-threading generally look like this:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def slow_function(input):
    ** opencv transforms and things **
    return output

worker_pool = Pool(4)
result = worker_pool.map(slow_function,list_of_inputs)
worker_pool.close()
worker_pool.join()
```

I've gotten this to work for my code, but I've been timing it and the line `worker_pool = Pool(4)` takes 100ms alone. The rest of the code runs very fast.

This creates a minimum overhead of 100ms, which makes in not particularly useful. My application is real time, so I would be capped at 10fps even if the rest of my code ran instantly.

It seems like I should be able to avoid creating and destroying the pool every cycle, thus saving those 100ms. Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I would like to call `map` then `join`, and just have the workers "forget" that they even ran anything once they run `slow_funcion` and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to not call `worker_pool.close()` and/or `worker_pool.join()` at all. That will keep your threads alive and available to process new data.

`worker_pool.map()` will take care of waiting for the threads to deliver a result anyway and will give you a synchronization point in your code.

You do need to keep your thread pool alive and available, though. Depending on your architecture, that may or may not be best made by wrapping it in an object (thus defining a `class`).

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Execution time went from 135ms (single thread), and 110ms (multi-threaded), to 40ms (multi-thread, re-used workers). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just spawn processes as need and use the Queue module to pass data between your main process and the "slow_function" process.